# The reason why the Nielsen-Nimiya Theorem doesn't have to hold true in the Floquet system?

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, lattice-model, floquet-theory

According to the Nielsen-Ninomiya (NN) theorem, **under appropriate assumptions**, the number of right-handed and left-handed particles must be equal in a lattice system. On the other hand, in recent years, Weyl fermion construction methods have been discussed in Floquet and non-Hermitian systems that violate NN theorem.

So, **which assumption in NN theorem is broken** in the Floquet system to escape the NN theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One assumption made in the early papers by Nielsen and Ninomiya [[Nucl. Phys. B 185, 20 (1981)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90361-8), [Nucl. Phys. B 193, 173 (1981)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90524-1)] is that the energy eigenvalues at each momentum can be ordered, i.e. $\epsilon_1 (\mathbf{p}) < \epsilon_2 (\mathbf{p}) < \dots < \epsilon_N (\mathbf{p})$ (with some allowance for some levels being degenerate). The eigenvalues of interest in a Floquet problem are the quasienergies, which are periodic up to $2\pi/T$ and thus cannot be ordered. Appropriate modifications to the Nielsen-Ninomiya-theorem have been discussed in the literature, see [X.-Q. Sun et al., Phys. Rev. Lett. 121, 196401 (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.196401) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.09296)) and [T. Bessho and M. Sato, Phys. Rev. Lett. 127, 196404 (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.196404) ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04204)).